# More pythonic way to handle this if condition?

Tags: python, if-statement

Let just suppose I have this condition, assume a and b are booleans already

```
if not a and b:
    do something
if a and not b:
    do something different
```

Is there any way to optimise it more, Any more pythonic way to handle this ?

Comment: What exactly is this check for? Also there would be no point of condensing it to one `if` if you are printing different things.

Comment: I agree , not possible with one if anyhow, any pythonic way to check this than?

Comment: It looks readable enough to me: I'd much rather see this that than someone trying to do something like: `print {a: 'this is a', b: 'this is b'}.get(a or b if not (a and b) else None, 'BOO!')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two conditions are excluding one another. You can rewrite it as:

```
if bool(a) != bool(b): # a xor b
    if a:
        print "a and not b"
    else:
        print "not a and b"
```

But it looks far more obscure. So for me the best way is:

```
if not a and b:
  print "not a and b"
elif a and not b:
  print "a and not b"
```

(note `elif` instead of `if`).

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are looking for an exclusive or (xor). Try this:

```
if a is not b:
    print "a xor b"
```

Comment: What if `a = 5`, then `a is not b` will evaluate True no matter what. `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`, which is not the same as `a == b`.

Comment: It's similar to `xor`, but there are two separate branches depending on which one of `a` and `b` is true.